# ansible - pass pattern as extra var

Tags: ansible

How do I fix following playbook to accept file pattern as an extra var and delete files with matching file pattern older than given no. of days?

```
---
- hosts: destination_servers
  vars:
   file_pattern: "{{ file_name }}"

  tasks:
  - name: Find all files older than {{ age }} days
    find:
     path: '{{ dir }}'
     file_type: file
     pattern: '{{ file_pattern }}'
     age: '{{ age }}'
     recurse: no
    register: files_to_delete
  - name: Remove files
    file:
     path: '{{ dir }}'
     file_type: file
     state: absent
    with_items: "{{ files_to_delete.files }}"
```

command to execute

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/servers.ini playbook/deleteFiles.yml -e "dir=/home/test/folder/ age=30d file_name=*.txt"
```

file_name can have any pattern like `*.* or *.txt or file*.txt or file*.*`

Answer (score -1):

Got the solution and following is the updated playbook

```
---
- hosts: destination_servers
  vars:
   file_pattern: '{{ file_name }}'

  tasks:
  - name: Find all files older than {{ age }} days
    find:
     paths: '{{ dir }}'
     file_type: file
     pattern: '{{ file_pattern }}'
     age: '{{ age }}'
     recurse: no
    register: files_to_delete
  - name: Remove files
    file:
     path: '{{ item.path }}'
     state: absent
    with_items: "{{ files_to_delete.files }}"
```

Comment: So the solution was to use simple quote when transfering the variable to another? Why setting a variable with the exact value instead of using directly `file_name` in the `find`?

Comment: Oh no, the solution was to actually delete the loop item instead of the directory.